# Помогите разобраться в сжатии данных ( кодирование переменной длины)

Tags: сжатие

FA FA FA FA FA CD CD FA FA FA FA 12 00 CD FA FA FA 12
есть вот такая последовательность в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. С помощью кодирования переменной длины мы получаем:
**FF 01 FA** CD CD **FF 00 FA** 12 00 CD FA FA FA 12

FA FA FA FA - это избыточная часть последовательности которую мы обозначаем как **FF 00 FA**

где FA FA FA FA FA - как **FF 01 FA**

где FF - без понятия как правильно назвать (слово, префикс, указатель ) на то что тут был избыточная часть последовательности и мы ее изменили для уменьшения объема данных.

где 00 - значит что тут 4 повторения.

а 01 = 4 + 1

FA - шестнадцатеричное значение которое является избыточным

в отношении 18 значений до кодирования и 15 после 
18/15=1,2
На 1 байт архивируемого потока данных прибывают 1,2 байта первоначального потока данных
(1 – 15 / 18) * 100 = Компрессия на 16,67 %

правильно ли я размышляю?

избыточная последовательность считается если значение повторяешься 4 и больше раз? 
информацию на эту тему не могу найти(

9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A B8 50 F7 F7 9A 9A 9A CC CC CC CC B8 F7 CC 48 48 48 48 9A
после компрессии должно быть так?
AA 03 9A B8 50 F7 F7 AA 00 9A CC CC CC CC B8 F7 CC 48 48 48 48 9A ?

Comment: Вообще существует довольно много алгоритмов сжатия. в том что вы привели, конечно _стоит считать_ повторы от 4х раз, иначе более короткие этот метод превратит в более длинные

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Только что нашел нужную информацию. Кодировка называется RLE - Run Length Encoding